# How to group by date and apply a formula to each group?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following `df`:

```
    DateTime            Var1
0   2021-08-01 10:00:00 115.0
1   2021-08-01 11:00:00 99.0
2   2021-08-01 12:00:00 155.0
3   2021-08-01 13:00:00 73.0
4   2021-08-01 14:00:00 44.0
5   2021-08-02 10:00:00 112.0
6   2021-08-02 11:00:00 100.0
7   2021-08-02 12:00:00 150.0
8   2021-08-02 13:00:00 70.0
9   2021-08-02 14:00:00 45.0
```

I need to group the data by date (not date and time), and apply `my_group` formula to each date.
This is how I did it:

```
def my_group(group):
    if len(group) == 0:
        return np.nan    
    return group["Var1"]/len(group)

result = (
    df[["DateTime","Var1"]]
        .assign(date=lambda x: x["DateTime"].dt.date)
        .groupby("date")
        .apply(my_group)
        .reset_index()
)

result.head()
```

But instead of grouping by date, the records seem to group differently, because I see the same date duplicated in the `result` (the `Var1` values come from my original `df`):

```
     date        level_1   Var1
0    2021-08-01  0         0.016767
1    2021-08-01  1         0.014398
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output is expected, because:

```
return group["Var1"]/len(group)
```

return Series like original DataFrame.

Need aggregation, e.g. `sum`:

```
return group["Var1"].sum()/len(group)
```

what is same like:

```
return group["Var1"].mean()
```

I think length of group is never `0` here, so solution should be simplify:

```
result = (
    df.groupby(df["DateTime"].dt.date.rename('date'))["Var1"].mean().reset_index()
)
print (result)
         date  Var1
0  2021-08-01  97.2
1  2021-08-02  95.4
```

Another solution with [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
result = (
    df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='d', key="DateTime"))["Var1"]
      .mean()
      .rename_axis('date')
      .reset_index()
)
```